# How do you go from $\frac12n(n+1) + (n+1)$ to $\frac12(n+1)(n+2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't understand how you can go from 
$$\frac12n(n+1) + (n+1)$$ to 
$$\frac12(n+1)(n+2)$$

What steps and rules are being applied here?

Comment: Please typeset your question using *MathJax* because your current question is ambiguous.  Does 1/2n(n+1) mean $\frac{1}{2n(n+1)}$?  or $\frac{1}{2n} (n+1)$? or $\frac{1}{2} n(n+1)$? or...

Comment: It's easy take $(n+1)$ common.

Answer (score 2):

Factoring $n+1$ from the expression gives $$\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)+(n+1)=(n+1)(\frac{1}{2}n+1)=\frac{1}{2}(n+1)(n+2)$$